# How to extract bounding box coordinates from a YolovV5 object detection model that has been converted to a CoreML model for use in an iOS app?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, object-detection, coreml, yolov5

Here is my coreMl model prediction

[image: 1]

I need something like that,

I need this kind of prediction

[image: 2]

I have tried it for export
!python export.py --weights /content/drive/MyDrive/best.pt --include "coreml"

Could any one know how can I convert correctly and get the bounding box, score, and other things?

Comment: Did u try apple sample project of live object detection with fruits.. That contain demo model and how to test it. BUt If you wan to first get model with rectangle bounding on image then u can using various Annotation tools and then use their CSV into .jSON in model training

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I have the exact same issue now.